# Using fields other then primary key as id during insert/update

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got this tables:

```
CREATE TABLE properties(
  id SERIAL,
  external_id VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE things(
  id SERIAL,
  external_id VARCHAR,
  property_id INTEGER,
  CONSTRAINT things_property_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (property_id)
  REFERENCES properties(id)
)
```

An external software needs to insert/update records in the tables, but has no knowledge of `id`-fields - only of `external_id`. So it can't just do

```
UPDATE things SET property_id = 'foo123' WHERE external_id ='Boo567'
```

- it has to find out the primary key of the record in the table `properties` with `external_id = "foo123"` first. What is the most efficient way to do this in Postgresql? `external_id` is indexed&unique.

UPDATE
Looks like I wasn't clear enough. The problem with the `UPDATE` statement above is that there is no record in `properties` where `id = 'foo123'`. But there is a record with `external_id = 'foo123'`, but I can't use `external_id` directly to reference the record.

Comment: You don't need the primary key for updates, so your `UPDATE` query should work. Do you get some kind of error or why do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: meanwhile FK creation should fail without PK... also if properties.external_id is unique, you should define it - they you should create FK `things.external_id references (properties.external_id)`, but then I don't see any point in `properties.id`...

Comment: I'm trying to set property_id without knowing the id of the record referenced. I only know it's external_id.

Comment: As mentioned - it looks like this update should work. Only issue I see is with using double quotes instead of single quotes.
`UPDATE things SET property_id = 'foo123' WHERE external_id ='Boo567'`

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Cameron is right. You're using the wrong quotation marks. When you use double-quotes you're telling it "use the value from field foo123", not "use the value foo123"

Comment: Please forget the syntax. I cannot reference a record in property_id in my update without knowing the record's primary key value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
UPDATE
    things
SET
    property_id = (
        SELECT id
        FROM properties
        WHERE external_id = 'foo123'
    )
WHERE
    external_id ='Boo567'
```

It's called a subquery.